# How to work with Camera of mobile device in Acumatica mobile framework

Tags: acumatica

In Acumatica framework for mobile applications is it possible to work with Mobile camera and bar code scanning? Or at least with camera? Is it possible to add some C# code, which will be running inside of Acumatica mobile application?

Comment: It is possible. The out-of-the-box Expense Receipt page in the mobile app has camera functionality available. If I'm not mistaken it adds the picture as an attachment.

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas can be found in I400 and the Help docs - Configuring attachments in Mobile and Enhancements taken from Camera:

https://help-2018r2.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=fd9cb8aa-609c-46d4-8c8d-f29dda804721

For the C# code, I am wondering if adding a View on Note or UploadFile/UploadFileDoc for given FileID/NoteID:

```
public PXSelect<UploadFile, Where<UploadFile.noteId, 
             Equal<Current<YourDAC.noteId>>>> Attachments;
```

and subscribing to UploadFile_RowPersisting or other event.